# vpnc does not log anything to rsyslog

Tags: networking, logs, vpn, rsyslog

I am using `vpnc-connect` and `vpnc-disconnect` (from package `vpnc`) on Debian 12.

when I start `vpnc-connect` it just prints message:

```
VPNC started in background (pid: 2345)
```

But other than that, the whole operation of these tools is completely silent. There are no logs, even when error occurs (ie, wrong password. It will just ask for password again on the propmt).

Where can I see the vpnc logs?
Are they not being logged in rsyslog via the daemon facility?

Do I have to set explicitly logging to be enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vpnc` is usually started with `vpnc` (at least by me...). If I need information, I start it with

```
vpnc --debug 3 <file>
```